# Proper filenames in iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been told during a job assignment review, that I used weird filenames in my iOS project.

I've added a picture of my project tree. Could you explain me what's weird about these names or if there are any flaws in the tree structure?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What did they say was "weird?" I don't like `+Ext`. The part after the `+` should describe what kind of extension it provides, not just be a general purpose "extensions." But that's not unusual. I'd have to know what else they said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Weirdness" is a subjective term and it isn't one that I would use to give feedback to someone in a review.

There is nothing "weird" about the names you have chosen. Perhaps the interviewer was unable to immediately ascertain what "Launches.swift" contained?

Are you able to ask the reviewer for more information about what they perceived as weird? It would be nice to understand more about their opinion.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I think. I will try, but not sure I can continue this conversation with him.

Answer (score 0):

> In general, the name of a source file best describes the primary
>   entity that it contains. A file that primarily contains a single type
>   has the name of that type. A file that extends an existing type with
>   protocol conformance is named with a combination of the type name and
>   the protocol name, joined with a plus (+) sign. For more complex
>   situations, exercise your best judgment.

source: https://google.github.io/swift/#file-names

For example:

MasterViewController -> LibraryMasterViewController

MasterPresenter -> BooksPresenter etc